# Regex to match a range of numbers

Tags: regex

I am using following regex to match the range between 1 and 9999.9 and it works good!

```
"^([1-9]|[1-9]\\d|[1-9]\\d\\d|[1-9]\\d\\d\\d)(\\.\\d)?$"
```

But, I want the range to start from 0.5 through 9999.9!

How can I do this! Any suggestion!

Comment: For God sake can you please enlighten me why to use regex for checking that number range?

Comment: "Any suggestion!" I would suggest not using a regular expression...!

Comment: thwn whats ur suggestion to validate range?

Comment: It depends what programming language you are using, but normally you would use a simple range test, e.g. `value >= 0.5 && value <= 9999.9`.

Comment: right now, I am using the one u just suggested! but, it doesn't look good in code (for all my range validations, right now I have 120 lines of code)!

Comment: using java with spring MVC and hibernate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, and you can also simplify the regex you already have:

```
"^(?:0\\.[5-9]|[1-9]\\d{0,3}(?:\\.\\d)?)$"
```